# Change Color of cell of grid

Tags: android, gridview, onclick

I want to change the color of the grid cell using the number of grid position . e.g. I have 5X6 grid means 30 gridItems so i want to change the color of 21st  position. Please tell me how can i do this Without clicking on the Grid View.

Comment: do you have an adapter with your gridview ?

Comment: then i don't see what is your issue. just change the color when you reach the 21st element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to define a custom adapter for this.
In the `getView()` method of adapter you'll have to check the `position` parameter if is equal with 21. If it's equal with 21, then change the background for currently cell.

If you did not had the experience to  define a custom adapter yet, then it will make more sense to pass through an example first.
Here's an example of a GridView that uses a [custom adapter to display images.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

Answer (score 0):

In order to set color in grid cell while inflating grid cell's layout, in your baseadapter class create a cell's array then set the color as you wish.

Like

```
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        grd = li.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
FrameLayout dgcl = (FrameLayout) grd.findViewById(R.id.grditm);
        parent_l[position] = dgcl;
```

then

```
parent_l[21].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

here griditm is the id of the layout grid_item

Answer (score -2):

First you must decide the order of the grid, where are columns, and where are lines. For example:

1 2 3 4 5

6 7 8 9 10

etc..

then just do a multiplication

```
i = Y*numberOfColums  + X;
grid[i].myColor = Color(R,G,B);
```

I'm assuming 0 based index, that simply means:
if there are 6 columns:

```
0 <= X <= 5
```

if there are 5 rows

```
0 <= Y <=4
```

0 based index allows you to iterate the whole grid in a very simple manner

```
for(int x = 0; x < numberOfColumns; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < numberOfRows; y++)
    {
        i = Y*numberOfColums  + X;
    }
}
```